# CSS - Facebook buttons dropping down after liking

Tags: css

We have this annoying layout issue. Please see the following url to see it in action:

http://www.businesseventsydney.com.au/home-page-test.cfm

The FB like buttons are neatly situated in the top nav bar. But, as soon as you click "Like" and enter a comment, the buttons drop down below the nav bar. If you refresh the page, the buttons appear correctly again.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
.fb-like {width: 128px !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi now **define** `height` of your `iframe` css as like this

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe{
height:244px !important;
border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
}


!important must give to this
```

Result is this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The element changes from having a width of 129px before liking etc, to having a width of 450px after liking.

So, you will have to make it fit into your design in a spot that allows for the worst case scenario, ie, 450px.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `#top-nav-right` css rule to:

```
#top-nav-right {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px 125px 0 0;
  width: 129px;
}
```